Use pl.when to create a list with same number of elements, but different content
I asked a similar question for Pandas already, but as I mentioned elsewhere, I am switching to Polars. So, now I need a solution for Polars doing the same thing:
I have a Polars DataFrame where a value sometimes gets NA (for Polars it's null (=None), if I got that correct). I want to fill this column with a list of strings with the same length as another column:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"a": ["one", "two"],
                   "b": ["three", "four"],
                   "c": [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
                   "d": [[5, 6], None]})




a
b
c
d




one
three
[1, 2]
[5, 6]


two
four
[3, 4]
NaN



and I want this to become



a
b
c
d




one
three
[1, 2]
[5, 6]


two
four
[3, 4]
[no_value, no_value]



I tried
df = df.with_columns(d = pl.when(pl.col('d').is_null())
                        #    .then(pl.Series([['no_value'] * len(lst) for lst in pl.col('c')])) # 'Expr' object is not iterable
                        #    .then(pl.Series([['no_value'] * pl.col('c').list.len()])) # failed to determine supertype of object and list[i64]
                        #    .then([['no_value'] * pl.col('c').list.len()]) # not yet implemented: Nested object types
                           .otherwise(pl.col('d')))


I seriously recommend just leaving it as None/null at that point, if you need to display it to the user at some point, change from None to a string at that point instead.
Storing strings and numbers within the same column is just not a good idea

Ok, this is just an example. In my real data all numbers are strings. Will change that in the question. Also this is already the point where I want to display it.

Use Expr.fill_null with a repeat_by expression to construct the list with the correct length:
df.with_columns(
    pl.col.d.fill_null(
        pl.lit("no_value").repeat_by(pl.col.c.list.len())
    )
)


That sounds good. I'll try that. For now, I changed the null returning function to return the desired value before collapsing. That might be cleaner.

In general, your approach using a when-then-otherwise construct is fine. You can use pl.Expr.repeat_by to repeat a scalar column into a list column.
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(
        pl.col("d").is_null()
    ).then(
        pl.lit("no_value").repeat_by(pl.col("c").list.len())
    ).otherwise(
        pl.col("d")
    ).alias("d")
)

shape: (2, 4)
┌─────┬───────┬───────────┬──────────────────────────┐
│ a   ┆ b     ┆ c         ┆ d                        │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---       ┆ ---                      │
│ str ┆ str   ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[str]                │
╞═════╪═══════╪═══════════╪══════════════════════════╡
│ one ┆ three ┆ [1, 2]    ┆ ["5", "6"]               │
│ two ┆ four  ┆ [3, 4]    ┆ ["no_value", "no_value"] │
└─────┴───────┴───────────┴──────────────────────────┘

